# Check which all records have duplicate using window function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am using `ROW_NUMBER()` to find duplicates, encapsulated under CTEs. I am using `ROW_NUMBER()` because I also want to have column which shows how many duplicate rows are present in the table.

The below code gives only records greater than 1. That is row number 2 and 3. But how can I include row number 1 of duplicate records?

If I removed `T>1`, than output also contain records which does not have duplicate like records with Part "'0020R5',100".

DDL:

```
DROP TABLE #TEST
CREATE TABLE #TEST
(
    PART VARCHAR(30),   
    ALTPART int
)

INSERT #TEST    
SELECT '15-AB78',100 UNION ALL
SELECT '15-AB78',110 UNION ALL
SELECT '16-A9-1',100 UNION ALL
SELECT '16-A9-1',110 UNION ALL
SELECT '16-B97-2',100 UNION ALL
SELECT '16-B97-2',110 UNION ALL
SELECT '0020R5',100
```

Query:

```
WITH TEST(PART,ALTPART,T) AS   
(  
    SELECT PART,ALTPART,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PART ORDER BY ALTPART ASC) AS T FROM #TEST   
)  
SELECT PART,ALTPART,T 
FROM TEST  
WHERE T>1
ORDER BY PART
GO

Current output:
 '15-AB78',110,2 
 '16-A9-1',110,2 
 '16-B97-2',110,2
```

Expected Result:

```
'15-AB78',100,1
'15-AB78',110,2 
'16-A9-1',100,1 
'16-A9-1',110,2 
'16-B97-2',100,1 
'16-B97-2',110,2
```

Comment: "The below code only filter the 1 records of duplicate where i am trying to have output including row no 1 for duplicates." - could you clarify this sentence? I cannot make sense of it.

Comment: @Alex: Hi Alex, i modofied the sentence, kindly help.... it seems little tricky.... Thanks

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you just need to remove `WHERE T>1` .... Is this a homework question?

Comment: @Alex: if i remove t>1, i will also get non duplicate record...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another window function **to count** the number of duplicates in each group.

Something along these lines:

```
WITH TEST(PART,ALTPART,DuplicateNum, DuplicateCnt) AS   
(  
    SELECT PART,ALTPART,
        -- Number each duplicate
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PART ORDER BY ALTPART ASC) AS DuplicateNum,
        -- Count duplicates
        COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY PART ) AS DuplicateCnt,
    FROM #TEST   
)  
SELECT PART, ALTPART, DuplicateNum
FROM TEST  
WHERE DuplicateCnt > 1
ORDER BY PART
```